# Attributes.add url in same browser window

Tags: html, window.open

```
courtSearchBtn.Attributes.Add("onclick", "window.open('"+ url + "', '_self')");
```

any help on what I can use to get it to open in the same window??

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could try using `_parent` and `_top`. The way I usually deal with this is using a function which has within it

```
window.location.href = newUrl
```